# Pandas -- asof() by last on DataFrame

Tags: pandas, cython

Say, we build a df:

```
import pandas as pd
import random as randy
import numpy as np
df_size = int(1e6)
df = pd.DataFrame({'first':       randy.sample(np.repeat([np.NaN,'Cat','Dog','Bear','Fish'],df_size),df_size),
               'second': randy.sample(np.repeat([np.NaN,np.NaN,'Cat','Dog'],df_size),df_size),
                'value': range(df_size)},
                index=randy.sample(pd.date_range('2013-02-01 09:00:00.000000',periods=1e6,freq='U'),df_size)).sort_index()
```

And it looks like this:

```
                            first   second    value
2013-02-01 09:00:00          Fish    Cat     95409
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000001   Dog     Dog     323089
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000002   Fish    Cat     785925
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000003   Dog     Cat     866171
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000004   nan     nan     665702
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000005   Cat     nan     104257
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000006   nan     nan     152926
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000007   Bear    Cat     707747
```

What I'd like is for each value in the 'second' column, I'd like the last 'value' of the first.

```
                            first   second   value  new_value
2013-02-01 09:00:00         Fish     Cat     95409    NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000001   Dog     Dog     323089   323089
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000002   Fish    Cat     785925   NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000003   Dog     Cat     866171   NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000004   nan     nan     665702   NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000005   Cat     nan     104257   NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000006   nan     nan     152926   NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000007   Bear    Cat     707747   104257
```

Perhaps, that isn't the absolute best example, but at the bottom, when 'second' is 'Cat', I'd like the most recent value when 'first' was 'Cat'

The real dataset has 1000+ categories so looping through symbol and doing an asof() seems prohibitively expensive. I've never had any luck with passing strings in Cython, but I suppose mapping symbols to ints and do a brute force loop would work -- I was hoping for something more pythonic. (That's still reasonably fast)

A reference, and somewhat fragile Cython hack would be:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
import sys
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.double_t DTYPE_t

def last_of(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] some_values,np.ndarray[long, ndim=1] first_sym,np.ndarray[long, ndim=1] second_sym):
    cdef long val_len = some_values.shape[0], sym1_len = first_sym.shape[0], sym2_len = second_sym.shape[0], i = 0
    assert(sym1_len==sym2_len)
    assert(val_len==sym1_len)
    cdef int enum_space_size = max(first_sym)+1

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] last_values = np.zeros(enum_space_size, dtype=np.double) * np.NaN
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] res = np.zeros(val_len, dtype=np.double) * np.NaN
    for i in range(0,val_len):
        if first_sym[i]>=0:
            last_values[first_sym[i]] = some_values[i]
        if second_sym[i]<0 or second_sym[i]>=enum_space_size:
            res[i] = np.NaN
        else:
            res[i] = last_values[second_sym[i]]
    return res
```

And then some dict replace nonsense:

```
syms= unique(df['first'].values)
enum_dict = dict(zip(syms,range(0,len(syms))))
enum_dict['nan'] = -1
df['enum_first'] = df['first'].replace(enum_dict)
df['enum_second'] = df['second'].replace(enum_dict)
df['last_value'] = last_of(df.value.values*1.0,df.enum_first.values.astype(int64),df.enum_second.values.astype(int64))
```

This has the problem that if the 'second' column has any values not in the first, you've got a problem. (I'm not sure of a fast way to fix this...say if you added 'donkey' to the second)

The cythonic stupid version per 10 million rows is ~ 21 sec for the whole mess, but only ~2 for the cython portion. (Which could be made a decent amount faster)

@HYRY -- I think this is a pretty solid solution; on a DF with 10 million rows, on my laptop, this takes about 30 seconds for me.

Given that I don't know of a simple way to handle when the second list has entries not in the first besides a pretty expensive isin, I think HYRY's python version is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

How about use a dict to keep the last value of every category, and iter all the rows in the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import random as randy
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
df_size = int(1e2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'first':       randy.sample(np.repeat([None,'Cat','Dog','Bear','Fish'],df_size),df_size),
               'second': randy.sample(np.repeat([None,None,'Cat','Dog'],df_size),df_size),
                'value': range(df_size)},
                index=randy.sample(pd.date_range('2013-02-01 09:00:00.000000',periods=1e6,freq='U'),df_size)).sort_index()

last_values = {}
new_values = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    t, f, s, v = row    
    last_values[f] = v
    if s is None:
        new_values.append(None)
    else:
        new_values.append(last_values.get(s, None))
df["new_value"] = new_values
```

The result is

```
                          first second  value new_value
2013-02-01 09:00:00.010373   Cat   None     87      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.013015   Cat    Dog     69      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.024910  Fish    Cat      1        69
2013-02-01 09:00:00.025943   Cat   None     98      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.041318  Fish    Dog     66      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.057894  None   None     36      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.059678  None   None     50      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.067228  Bear   None     38      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.095867  Bear    Cat     84        98
2013-02-01 09:00:00.096867   Dog    Cat     97        98
2013-02-01 09:00:00.101540   Dog    Dog     76        76
2013-02-01 09:00:00.106753   Dog   None     22      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.138936  None   None      8      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.139273  Bear    Cat      2        98
2013-02-01 09:00:00.143180  Fish   None     94      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.184757  None    Cat     73        98
2013-02-01 09:00:00.193063  None   None      5      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.231056  Fish    Cat     62        98
2013-02-01 09:00:00.237658  None   None     64      None
2013-02-01 09:00:00.240178  Bear    Dog     80        22
```

Comment: This is pretty good -- it's really a lot faster than I would expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know but here's a solution avoiding any Python loops. 
The first step is to get a time series of `'value'` for each category. 
You can do this by unstacking:

```
first_values = df.dropna(subset=['first']).set_index('first', append=True).value.unstack()    
second_values = df.dropna(subset=['second']).set_index('second', append=True).value.unstack()
```

Note that this will only working if the columns contain true `NaN` values rather than `'nan'` strings (do `df = df.replace('nan', np.nan)` to prepare if necessary).

You can then get the last first value by forward filling `first_values`, reindexing like `second_values`, stacking again and indexing into the result using the original `'time', 'second'` pairs:

```
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index, df.second])
new_value = first_values.ffill().reindex_like(second_values).stack().reindex(ix)
df['new_value'] = new_value.values

In [1649]:    df
Out[1649]:
                           first    second  value   new_value
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000000  Fish    Cat     95409   NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000001  Dog     Dog     323089  323089
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000002  Fish    Cat     785925  NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000003  Dog     Cat     866171  NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000004  NaN     NaN     665702  NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000005  Cat     NaN     104257  NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000006  NaN     NaN     152926  NaN
2013-02-01 09:00:00.000007  Bear    Cat     707747  104257
```